# Halcon - Stretch a region

Tags: region, stretch, halcon

How can a region be stretched?

If I have a region, of any shape, and want to stretch it horizontally, but not vertically, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the operator zoom_region(Region : RegionZoom : ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight : ).
In your case ScaleHeight=1

Comment: could you PLEASE have a look at this problem? It's driving me crazy and I think you have the needed knowledge.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64371266/halcon-3d-equivalent-of-affine-trans-contour-xld

Comment: I reply to your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64355720/halcon-extend-region-where-it-intersects-with-another-region/64373034#64373034.

Comment: There you can find another manner to do a region stretch